# How to add submit function to my ng-controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn angular so forgive my stupid mistakes and ignorance. That being said,
I add data to my scope when I create my controller ProducerCtrl. This works before I add anything else. When I add the addname function it breaks my data fetch. I am sure I am doing something wrong because I don't know what I am doing. I would like to have these
two bits of code work. Maybe I need to move one or both to another area.

```
<html><head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var eventApp = angular.module('eventApp', []);

var szAction = "/GoGetData";
var szAction2 = "/GoPostData" })";

eventApp.controller('ProducerCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function (scope, http) {
    http.get(szAction).success(function (data) {
        scope.producer = data;
    });

    $scope.addName = function () {
        http.post(szAction2, scope.producer);

    };
}]);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="eventApp">
    <div ng-controller="ProducerCtrl">
        Name:<input ng-model="producer.Name" type="text" /><br>
        Hello {{producer.Name}}

        <form ng-submit="addName()">
            <input ng-model="producer.Name" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="add">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: `var szAction2 = "\GoPostData" })";` should be getting an error for this line

Comment: and `$scope.addName` probably should be `scope.addName` as your variable name is `scope` not `$scope`, so you should be getting an error on that line as well. And you are escaping the letter `G` in your `szAction` variables, probably are wanting to use `/`

Comment: `http.post('/someUrl', data).success(successCallback);`

Comment: I put a fake url in there because it wasn't part of my question, however you guys are correct and I will fix it in my example. Like I said the get data part was working before I added the addName function.

Comment: Patrick was right about the dollar sign, If you want to put your comment into an answer I will give you the credit for the solution.

Comment: Check it: http://plnkr.co/edit/CJtEzGr4UtbmJxpp0FeK?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes on your code. When you click on add will prompt an alert.

Your HTML:

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="eventApp">
        <div ng-controller="ProducerCtrl">
            Name:<input ng-model="producer.Name" type="text" /><br />
            Hello {{producer.Name}}

            <form ng-submit="addName()">
                <input ng-model="producer.Name" type="text" />
                <input type="submit" value="add" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<body>
```

Your Angular code:

```
var eventApp = angular.module('eventApp', []);

eventApp.controller('ProducerCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.producer = { Name : '' };

    $scope.addName = function () {
        alert($scope.producer.Name);
    };
}]);
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LMk4j/12/).

Take a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) to check $http.